# Wierd names in import table

Tags: pe, dll, static-analysis, functions

I'm trying to do a static analysis of a PE file to see what it does.
While doing so, I stumbled upon some really wierd function names in my objdump

```
DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
c2c68    1371  wcsncmp
c2c72    1017  _wcsnicmp
c2c7e    1229  iswdigit
c2c8a    1013  _wcslwr_s
c2c96    1225  iswalpha
c2ca2       5  ??0bad_cast@@QAE@ABV0@@Z
c2cbe      14  ??1bad_cast@@UAE@XZ
c2cd4    1241  localeconv
c2ce2    1256  memchr
c2cec    1304  strcspn
c2cf6    1292  sprintf_s
c2d02     884  _strtoi64
```

notice the 2 bad_cast functions. Why are they wierd looking like that? What does this syntax mean?

Comment: These are mangled C++ symbols. See for example [here](https://demangler.com/).

Comment: Awesome! Please post this comment as the answer and I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: Use `undname`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @guntram-blohm says, these are mangled C++ functions. If you demangle the names (using, for example, an [online demangler](https://demangler.com/)) you will get the fully decorated function names:

```
public: __thiscall bad_cast::bad_cast(class bad_cast const &)
public: virtual __thiscall bad_cast::~bad_cast(void)
```

So these functions are the constructor and the destructor for [bad_cast objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast), used to thrown an exception *when a dynamic_cast to a reference type fails the run-time check*.