# How do I interpret the mangled functions name?

Tags: binary-analysis

I am going to start by saying that this is my fourth attempt at reverse engineering a crackme and I'm starting to understand how assembly works, which is cool. I am sorry if this question is wrong or if I used the wrong terminology.

I am reversing a mach-0 binary with IDA. When I examine it, I find that there are hundreds of functions with weird names, like this

```
j___ZNSt3__1plIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS_12basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEPKS6_RKS9_
```

Now, this doesn't look like pure junk. From it I can 'extract' the following: char_traits, allocator, basic_string.

Apparently it does something with strings, as before there are the following instructions:

```
lea rsi, goodWork ; "Good work!"
lea rdx, _cido ; _cido in IDA is shown to do -> and [rax], eax ; I have no idea what that means
lea rdi, [rbp+var] ; the only occurrence of var before is at the start -> var = qword ptr - 1C0H ; as always, no idea of what is this
call to_the_function_I_wrote_before
jmp $+5
```

Is there a technique/way of knowing whatever this function does?

EDIT:

This has been flagged as a duplicate. It's not. The question you've linked only demangles the function name, which is a thing that IDA automatically does.

I need to understand whatever the hell this function does. The demangled function name is to me as helpful as the mangled one. I don't get it. I need a bit of guidance with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wierd names in import table](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12816/wierd-names-in-import-table)

Comment: .. Using the online demangler on your name results in the slightly bewildering `j__std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)` – originally, probably some typedefs or classes or summink like that.

Comment: Re your edit, it may be useful to post the demangled name to StackOverflow since it’s more of a programming question than RE per se

Comment: The `_cido` pointer equals to address of `and [rax], eax`, because IDA shows you data section as code section. It may however be a pointer to char, a table of ints, a pointer to pointer to pointer. That is, a pointer to almost anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually quite a straightforward C++ string function. It's just that, behind the scenes, the C++ `std::string` class is actually a typedef of a template.

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

basic_string itself is declared as -

```
template< class CharT, 
          class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
          class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
        > class basic_string;
```

In other words, a `std::string` is really a -

```
std::basic_string< char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
```

Applying this in reverse to your mangled name and (and removing the __1's - see below) your function is simply the standard library string function -

```
std::string operator+( char const* lhs, std::string const& rhs )
```

This concatenates a C style string and a std::string, returning the result as a new std::string.

This function is called from x86-64 assembly language as follows -

- `rdi` is a pointer to caller allocated memory for the returned std::string
- `rsi` is the first argument and hence a pointer to a C style (zero terminated) string
- `rdx` is the second argument and hence a reference (or pointer is assembly language terms) to a C++ std::string

Details on calling convention can be found here [AMD64 ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf)

---

In the above, I've ignored the __1 parts of the symbol. For details on where these come from see the following questions:

- [Where does the __1 come from when using LLVM's libc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293394/where-does-the-1-symbol-come-from-when-using-llvms-libc)
- [What are inline namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for)

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks. One thing though, I still don't get how you managed to figure out that the function concatenates a C string and an std::string. I guess that `basic_string` is the C++ string, but where is the C string? and where is the concatenator part?

Comment: @A.Dandelion In `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
(char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> const&)` replace all the `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` with `std::string` (`std::string` is just a `typedef` for that). It gives you: `std::string std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
(char const*, std::string const&)`.

Comment: @A.Dandelion Now, `std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` means that this operator belongs to class `<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>`, which is `std::string`. Therefore, it can be shortened to: `std::string std::string::operator+(char const*, std::string const&)`.

Comment: @anx199 Thanks. I think I am starting to get it. Isn't there a tool that does this for me though?