# Understanding obscure function names

Tags: disassembly, c++, pe, functions

I have seen functions like this before in disassembly but don't have a clue what they are. Their names are extremely confusing. Would someone be able to explain what these are?

[image: Picture of disassembly]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I interpret the mangled functions name?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/how-do-i-interpret-the-mangled-functions-name)

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for linking me to that question! I tried to find one that addressed this and didn’t come across that one! Thank you again!